# Saving dropdown list value to database ASP.net 5.0 MVC 6 using tag helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to save my dropdown list values to my database in an ASP.NET web application using MVC6 and Entity Framework 7 but the values are not saving.

I have two classes one called expenses and when a user creates an expense they need to select a country.  I have the country dropdown list populating but when the expense is saved the countryid is not being saved to the database.

Models

```
public class Country
{        public int Countryid { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}

public class Expense
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Countryid { get; set; }
```

Expense Controller

```
 private void PopulateCountriesDropDownList(object selectedCountry = null)
    {
        var list = _context.Countries.OrderBy(r => r.CountryCode).ToList().Select(rr =>

        new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Countryid.ToString(), Text = rr.CountryCode }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Countries = list;
    }
    // GET: Expenses/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateCountriesDropDownList();
                   return View();
    }

    // POST: Expenses/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Expenses.Add(expense);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        PopulateCountriesDropDownList(expense.Countryid);

        return View(expense);
    }
```

View

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Countryid" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="Countryid" class="form-control"asp-items=@ViewBag.Countries></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Countryid" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `Countryid` property in your Expense model is a of a complex type (`Country`). The model binder cannot map the posted `Countryid` form value to this Complex object.

You should add a CountryId property to your Expense model of type Int

```
public class Expense
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { set;get;}
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }    
}
```

While this will fix the problem, A more better & clean solution is to use a view model for transferring data between your view and action method. With this approach your view is not tightly coupled to the entity classes generated by your ORM.

So create a view model for your ***view with properties absolutely needed for the view***.

```
public class CreateExpenseVm
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Countries { set;get;}
   public int CountryId { set;get;}
   //Add other properties, if your view need them.
}
```

and in your GET action, you create an object of this class, load the Countries collection property and send it to your view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm=new CreateExpenseVm();
   vm.Countries = _context.Countries.OrderBy(r => r.CountryCode)
                       .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value=x.CountryId.ToString(),
                                                       Text=x.CountryCode}).ToList();
   return View(vm);
}
```

And in your view,which is strongly typed to our new viewmodel,

```
@model CreateExpenseVm
<form asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Create">      
    <label>Select Country</label>
    <select asp-for="CountryId" asp-items="@Model.Countries" >
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and in your HttpPost action, Use `CreateExpenseVm` as the parameter type. When the form is submitted, the default model binder will be able to map the posted form data to the properties of this class object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateExpenseVm model)
{
   var e=new Expense { CountryId=model.CountryId };
   e.ExpenseDate = DateTime.Now;
   dbContext.Expenses.Add(e);
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```